# Rank = # of non-zero eigenvalues of a diagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-rank

Is the rank of a matrix equal to the # of non-zero eigenvalues of a diagonalizable matrix?

Comment: Yes. For more information (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349907/what-is-the-relation-between-rank-of-a-matrix-its-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors)

Comment: Yes if you count with multiplicity. $T\colon V\to V$ is diagonalisable iff $V=\bigoplus_\lambda\ker(T-\lambda I)$.