# Eigenvalues of symmetric matrices with given information

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Why is it obvious that  a matrix **A** has an eigenvalue $\lambda_4=0$ if we know that **A** is symmetric 4x4 matrix, has a double eigenvalue 5 and another simple eigenvalue of -1, and rank 3?

Comment: Nope the statement above is wrong, consider this $\text{diag}(5,5,-1,a,b)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary.

Comment: I have modified the information.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349907/what-is-the-relation-between-rank-of-a-matrix-its-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors

Comment: I don't think it answers my question since in the information I have, the matrix has full rank. According to the article, if 0 is an eigenvalue then the rank is n-1. This seems conflicting to me for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** the eigenspace relative to zero corresponds to the solution space or $Ax=0$. So..