# Evaluate eigenvalues and algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue efficiently (with hand)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

For
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{lllll}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

Using MATLAB, one can easily show that $\lambda_1 = 0\,\,\,\,\,\&\,\,\,\,\lambda_2 = 5$ are the eigenvalues of the $A$.

However, I would like to do it by hand.

Since $det(A) = 0$, we know that $\lambda_1 = 0$ is an eigen value.

However, I am having difficulty finding the other value. I know if we take $det(A-\lambda I) = 0$, then we get the characteristic equation and can find eigenvalues.

But, I think it is too much to do for such a special matrix.

On the other hand, if I can establish that algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_1 = 0$ is $4$, then I can say that since $A$ must $5$ eigenvalues (not necessarily different), and $4$ of them being equal to $0$, then the other eigenvalue $\lambda_2 = \sum{a_{ii}} - 4 * \lambda_1 = 5 - 4*0 = 5$.

Is it possible to efficiently compute the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_1 = 0$ as $4$ by observing the matrix?

Comment: You can write down all of the eigenvectors very explicitly. For starters, the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $5$ is $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$.

Comment: I don't want to compute eigenvectors at all. May I know the reason why you suggested that?

Comment: It is by far the fastest way to do this computation. You can also do it by computing the characteristic polynomial using row reduction, but it is genuinely really easy to compute the eigenvectors, I promise.

Comment: How did you find 5 is an eigenvalue?

Comment: Multiply the matrix by the vector $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$!

Comment: How did you get this magic vector?

Comment: It's not magic! Just look at what the matrix actually *does*! It takes a vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ and returns the vector all of whose entries are the sum $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5$. In other words, the range is $1$-dimensional and spanned by $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ so this is the only possible eigenvector corresponding to a nonzero eigenvalue, and the other eigenvectors must have eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117150/discussion-between-sai-nikhil-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: Is there any relation between algebraic multiplicity and $dim(ker(A-\lambda I))$?

Comment: In general, try to plug in the vector $(1, \zeta, \zeta^2, \zeta^3, \zeta^4) $, where $\zeta$ is a 5-th root of unity. Since there are five of them, you will get five distinct eigenvectors. This works any time the row below is obtained by shifting positions by one. For example if the first row is $1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5$ , the second should be $ 2\ 3 \ 4 \ 5 \ 1$, and so on for the following rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that $A$ has $\mbox{rank}(A)=1$. Therefore, by the rank-nullity theorem, the Nullspace of $A$ has dimension $4$.

This means that the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ is 4-dimensional.

It is a fundamental result of Linear algebra that the multiplicity of an eigenvalue is greater or equal to the dimension of the eigenspace. [This is typically stated as "algebraic multiplicity" $\geq$ "geometric multiplicity"]

This means that $\lambda=0$ has multiplicity $4$.

It follows that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_4=0$.

Finally,
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4+\lambda_5= \mbox{tr}(A)=5$$

This gives $\lambda_5=5$.

Answer (score 0):

The columns are eigenvectors
$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4    \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: Can you please tell me how you found eigen values?

Comment: @SaiNikhil put your matrix on the left and this matrix on the right and multiply. I know this because the question has come up many hundreds of times

Comment: I still don't get how does multiplying two matrices give eigenvalues

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Note that it is a symmetric matrix, there are four linearly dependent row/column vectors i.e. all the row(column) vectors can be linearly expressed by a single row(column) vector. So treating the matrix as a transformation matrix we see that as the row vectors spans only one dimension, the transformed vectors will also span only one dimension. So there is only one non zero real eigenvalue. Rest all eigenvalues has to be zero.

Also for a matrix like above it is easy to see the the eigen vector for the non zero eigenvalue is type $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\.\\.\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ for ex. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\1 & 2 & 1\\1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \lambda\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} $ then 

$x+2y+z = \lambda x, x+2y+z = \lambda y, x+2y+z = \lambda z$,
so $x=y=z$. This also independently confirms that there is only one non zero eigenvalue.


If you want more technical view you can see this. [What is the relation between rank of a matrix, its eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349907/what-is-the-relation-between-rank-of-a-matrix-its-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors)

Comment: Okay, seems like you're the only one who read my question correctly. Just one more doubt before I upvote and tick. Can you mathematically write "row vectors spans only one dimension $\implies$ only $1$ non-zero eigenvalue"?

Comment: @SaiNikhil I edited my answer to clarify further.

Comment: The second part what I wrote was incorrect so I deleted it. But still the first part and the link should be fine.

Comment: and I added what I should have written then.