# Relation between eigenvalues and rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, diagonalization

> Prove/Disprove: Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n $ then rank of $A$ is atleast number of non zero eigenvalues of $A.$

My approach: For any matrix $A$, $A^TA$, and $AA^T$ are both symmetric and hence diagonalizable so the rank of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ are the same and are equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

Also, we know one result that for any real matrix $A$, $$\operatorname{rank}(A^TA)=\operatorname{rank}(AA^T)=\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^T).$$

Using the two above facts can we say that the statement is proven?

and to justify "atmost" take
\begin{equation}A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0  & 0 & 0 &0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
here rank of $A$ is $3$ which is greater than the number of non zero eigenvalues of $A$ that is $2$.

Is my approach okay or is there any nice explanation to justify the statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question may help: What is the relation between rank of a matrix, its eigenvalues and eigenvectors? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1349907/1215020

Comment: @CésarVB Thanks, that is a very interesting approach, but I need to know if my logic is right or if it has some problem if had written in some exam.

Answer (score 0):

You claimed the following

> 1. the rank of $A^TA$
>    and $AA^T$
>    are equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

> 2. The rank of $A$ is the same of the rank of $AA^T$.

From the above we deduce that $rank(A)$ is the same as the number of non-zero eigenvalues. Which your chosen example proves is False.

It is in fact the first statement which is wrong.

---

I guess the classical approach to prove this statement is to use the rank nullity theorem and point out that the kernel is an eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$

Comment: @Maths I don't understand what you are saying. Could you rephrase that and maybe use punctuation to clarify what you mean ?