# Principal Component Analysis software

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software, image-processing

I'm looking for a (non-MATLAB) software that can process a image using the PCA algorithm and output it like this:

[image: PCA example]

Regards.

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92171) As long as you can find software that can do SVD, you can do PCA.

Answer (score 0):

I see several examples of how to use PCA method on data using [this link that searches DataMelt project](http://jwork.org/dmelt/search/form.php?query=PCA). The implementation is in Java  (non-MATLAB), but you can use several other languages.